# Simple way to convert htm to pdf on button click?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I've created a htm file with php code inside, that's very huge file i will summarize here.

```
<?php
//database connection and query and storing data in php variables 
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php echo "firstname ". $var1 ?></p>
<p><?php echo "firstname ". $var2 ?></p>
<p><?php echo "firstname ". $var3 ?></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting output .htm file with echoing php variables successfully, now end of html file I want to create a button for save as pdf option and convert the entire document to pdf for user using php, I gone through tcpdf file but didn't find any useful source to add php code within $html.

Comment: Either output buffer the script execution that generates the html file or save it as a file, than pass that to tcpdf or dompdf or mpdf or any of the other libraries that convert html to pdf... there shouldn't be any PHP in the __output__ of the script, so why do you need a way of adding php code to $html?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to install `wkhtmltopdf` library and then call the 'exec' function to generate pdf from html.

```
exec('wkhtmltopdf http://google.pl google.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just refer dompdf.  I think it is easy to convert in pdf.

refer: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF is simple and easy to use...

http://www.tcpdf.org/ here you can find examples and can use them...

Also, I have problem with UTF-8 characters from MySql, for everything else is very good..

Pavle

Answer (score 0):

http://pd4ml.com/php.htm is a step-by-step instruction how to implement "As PDF" button (and to hide the button in the resulting PDF) using PD4ML.

Answer (score 0):

A simple html generating library for PHP can be here:

http://fpdf.org

just go through it.